# How to achieve notifications whenever there is change in Firebase Firestore Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There are two types of apps one which will be used by users and the other which will be used by me i.e the owner. So whenever any users add a content (data) to the Cloud Firestore database, I want to get notified. In short, how to send notifications whenever there is a change in Cloud Firestore database?

Comment: You can set up [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message) to send a notification to your token ID which you might store somewhere in the database and update it everytime you use your(owner's) app. It uses Firebase functions, which can be triggered on data changes in firestore.

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50663966/7639541 answer, this is what you want. if you need any other help in cloud function let me know.

Answer (score 27):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases). This will help you notify users when something interesting happens, in your case, when users will add content (data) to the database. In order to make it work, you need to implement [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). This will help you send notifications to a particular user or to a group of users when something new happens.

So, please consider follow the steps below.

First, implement `Firebase Authentication`. As soon as it is implemented, create a collection of users in which each user will be a document within users collection. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users (collection)
          |
          --- uid1 (document)
          |    |
          |    --- //user properties
          |
          --- uid2 (document)
               |
               --- //user properties
```

Beside user details, you also need to add to each user a `tokenId`. You get can it very simply using the following line of code:

```
String tokenId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

A user document should look like this:

```
uid1 (document)
 |
 --- userName: "John"
 |
 --- userEmail: john@email.com
 |
 --- tokenId: "e_wLukMfq..." //very long token
 |
 --- //other specific user details
```

Second, create a new collection within user document named `notifications`, in which you should add all the notifications that you need to send to the admin. The properties that are needed are `notification message` and the `sender`. The user document should look something like this:

```
    uid1 (document)
     |
     --- userName: "John"
     |
     --- userEmail: john@email.com
     |
     --- tokenId: "e_wLukMfq..." //very long token
     |
     --- notifications (collection)
     |      |
     |      --- notificationId1
     |              |
     |              --- notificationMessage: "My Notification"
     |              |
     |              --- fromUser: "My Notification"
     |
     --- //other details
```

Please see the nested `notifications` collection which is hosted beneath user's document.

Now you need to use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to write a function in `Cloud Functions` that will listen for every new notification that appears within this reference:

```
    "users/{uid}/notifications/{notificationId}"
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pf78y6ch/)** is a straightforward example of how you can write the Node.js function.

Once a new notification appears, you can use `sendToDevice` function and the `tokenId` to send the notification to a specific user. The notification will be handled by the Android system and will be displayed to the user. Note, this will work only when the app is in `background`. You can receive notifications also when the app is in `foreground` by implementing `FirebaseMessagingService`.

I also have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can **[send notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** as you need to.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Is it not better to create a new root collection "Notifications" with a reference to the user to avoid nesting and eventual trigger loops? It also keeps the User isolated from Notification information.

Comment: @Mikael There is not a better or the best solution. That might be another solution and if it works for you, go ahead with that ;)

Comment: As Firebase is a very specific storage type, it comes with special constraints as well. The way data is stored can also change drastically the queries performances (especially when the system scales) that's why I think that giving -by default - good advices about how data can be structured to support good scalability is a nice way to start. Of course I agree on the fact that each software has its own constraints.

Comment: will very helpful for me, can anyone share step by step for iOS?