# Can't understand how notifications on data change work with Firestore in android. Can anyone explain?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification

As I have said in the title, I can't understand how notifications works when data is changed in Firestore. I have an app that requires notifications to a certain group of users when data is added or existing documents are changed in the database.

I understand how notification channels work with the UI but not how to setup my app to respond to changes in the database in the background when the app isn't running. I can send a notification directly from the console in FireStore. The issue is as stated when data changes in the database. I'm coding in Android Studio with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203148/how-to-achieve-notifications-whenever-there-is-change-in-firebase-firestore-andr) is a similar question, following: the highlights.

I think you might consider use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases). This will help you notify users when something interesting happens in the database. In order to make it work, you need to implement [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). This will help you send notifications to a particular user or to a group of users when something new happens.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pf78y6ch/) is a straightforward example of how you can write the Node.js function.

Once a new notification appears, you can use `sendToDevice` function and the `tokenId` to send the notification to a specific user. The notification will be handled by the Android system and will be displayed to the user. Note, this will work only when the app is in `background`. You can receive notifications also when the app is in the foreground by implementing `FirebaseMessagingService`.

There is also explained in one [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee) step by step, how you can [send notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17) as you need to.